# What is the name of this quantum gate?

Tags: logic, quantum-computing

As I was watching a video about single qubit quantum gates, I came across the following gate:
$$\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\sigma}&0\\0&e^{i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$ The video didn't mention the name of the gate. It gave only the matrix and the following information:

- $|0\rangle \rightarrow e^{i\sigma}|0\rangle$
- $|1\rangle \rightarrow e^{i\theta}|1\rangle$
- $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \rightarrow \alpha e^{i\sigma}|0\rangle + \beta e^{i\theta}|1\rangle$

In the comments below the video, someone asked what $\sigma$ and $\theta$ could be, and the reply was all real numbers, but this was from someone other than the video maker, so I don't know if this is true.

What is the name of this gate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [phase shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Phase_shift_gates) gate.

Notice that

$$\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\sigma}&0\\0&e^{i\theta}\end{bmatrix}=
e^{i\sigma}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&e^{i(\theta-\sigma)}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Multiplying the state by a constant (with unit norm) will not affect your measurements.